# How to assign new file to package in postinst script

Tags: debian, dpkg, packaging

In the postinst script of a Debian package, I create and install a file with a name not known in advance. How can I assign that file to the package so it shows up in `dpkg-query --search` as belonging to the package?

Comment: That's now how it is supposed to work. Why do you need the file to be added afterwards, or why do you need it to show up in the dpkg query?

Comment: I know that this is not the standard way to do it. During installation, I copy configuration files from a repository. The contents of the repository might change. I want the files to show up in dpkg-query to be able to determine whether they belong to a package or were created by the user.